# Converting dictionary values in python from str to int in nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I currently have a nested dictionary which looks like this:

```
series = { 

'a': {'foo':'2', 'bar':'3', 'baz':'7', 'qux':'1'},
'b': {'foo':'6', 'bar':'4', 'baz':'3', 'qux':'0'},
'c': {'foo':'4', 'bar':'5', 'baz':'1', 'qux':'6'}
}
```

And I'm trying to convert the values from strings into integers.

I have tried this method:

```
newseries = dict((k,int(v)) for k,v in series.items())
```

But all I get is an error message saying:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'dict'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to go deeper in this case:

```
In [4]: {k: {kk: int(vv) for kk, vv in v.items()}
         for k, v in series.items()}
Out[4]: 
{'a': {'bar': 3, 'baz': 7, 'foo': 2, 'qux': 1},
 'b': {'bar': 4, 'baz': 3, 'foo': 6, 'qux': 0},
 'c': {'bar': 5, 'baz': 1, 'foo': 4, 'qux': 6}}
```

Your own example just iterates the key, value -pairs of *series*, which has (nested) `dict` values.

Note that this is not a generic solution. For that you'd need recursion or a stack.

Answer (score 0):

int(v)  -- *v is a  dictionary!*

**this line here, you are trying to convert a dictionary to an integer.**

you'll need to nest another dictionary comprehension inside

basically if you replace [int(v)] with something like

```
[dict((a,int(b) for (a,b) in v.items())]
```

didn't test that out but you get the idea, also nesting that might get a little messy

i suggest just writing a function that takes a dictionary and converts it's values from strings to int and then you can just replace [int(v)] with something like

```
 [convertDictValsToInts(v)]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example `v` is the internal dictionary, not the internal values. What you want to do is turn all values in the internal dict into an int.

```
{k1: {k2: int(v2) for k2, v2 in series[k1].items()} for k1 in series}
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Ilja Everilä, if you want a generic solution for all kinds of nested `dict`, you can use a recursive function.

I guess something like the following would work (will test it when I have some more time).

```
def series_to_int(series):
    for k,v in series.items():
        if type(v) == dict:
            series_to_int(v)
        elif type(v) == str:
            series[k] = int(v)
```

Note that the above routine will changes your `series` in-place. If you want a more functional approach (with a return value that you can use like `int_series = series_to_int(series)`, you'll have to tweak it a little.