# How to convert all values of a nested dictionary into strings?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am writing a python application where I have a variable dictionary that can be nested upto any level.

The keys in any level can be either int or string. But I want to convert all keys and values at all levels into strings. How nested the dictionary will be is variable which makes it a bit complicated.

```
{
    "col1": {
        "0": 0,
        "1": 8,
        "2": {
            0: 2,
        }
        "3": 4,
        "4": 5
    },
    "col2": {
        "0": "na",
        "1": 1,
        "2": "na",
        "3": "na",
        "4": "na"
    },
    "col3": {
        "0": 1,
        "1": 3,
        "2": 3,
        "3": 6,
        "4": 3
    },
    "col4": {
        "0": 5,
        "1": "na",
        "2": "9",
        "3": 9,
        "4": "na"
    }
}
```

I am looking for the shortest and quickest function to achieve that. There are other questions like [Converting dictionary values in python from str to int in nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37635549/converting-dictionary-values-in-python-from-str-to-int-in-nested-dictionary) that suggest ways of doing it but none of them deals with the "variable nesting" nature of the dictionary.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Something similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254454/fastest-way-to-convert-a-dicts-keys-values-from-unicode-to-str

Answer (score 6):

This is the most straightforward way I can think of doing it:

```
import json

data = {'col4': {'1': 'na', '0': 5, '3': 9, '2': '9', '4': 'na'}, 'col2': {'1': 1, '0': 'na', '3': 'na', '2': 'na', '4': 'na'}, 'col3': {'1': 3, '0': 1, '3': 6, '2': 3, '4': 3}, 'col1': {'1': 8, '0': 0, '3': 4, '2': {0: 2}, '4': 5}}
stringified_dict = json.loads(json.dumps(data), parse_int=str, parse_float=str)
```

Here are some links to the documentation for json loads and parse_int: [Python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load), [Python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load)

Comment: Hey, works great with int, float, "constant" -- not sure what that is, but its not able to convert bool or an array. Any good options for this? Should cover all except bool..

Comment: Is there an argument for `parse_path` for working with `pathlib.Path` objects?

Answer (score 5):

You could check the dictionary recursively:

```
def iterdict(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            iterdict(v)
        else:
            if type(v) == int:
                v = str(v)
            d.update({k: v})
    return d
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it's helpful to anyone, I modified [Jose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7356109/jose-angel-sanchez)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54565277/11144931) to handle lists as well.  The output converts *all* values to strings.  I haven't thoroughly tested it, but I just ran it against around 40k records, and it passed schema validation:

```py
def iterdict(d):
    """Recursively iterate over dict converting values to strings."""

    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            iterdict(v)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for x, i in enumerate(v):
                if isinstance(i, (dict, list)):
                    iterdict(i)
                else:
                    if type(i) != str:
                        i = str(i)
                    v[x] = i
        else:
            if type(v) != str:
                v = str(v)
            d.update({k: v})
    return d
```